# How to get the value of last assigned property in Sass or CSS?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I know of the `inherit` and `initial` properties, but I don't want them. I want to give the same value of the last CSS rule. Basically, a placeholder or dummy.

The reason I want to do this is because I'm using the Compass mixin link-colors:

```
@mixin link-colors($normal, $hover: false, $active: false, $visited: false, $focus: false) {
  color: $normal;
  @if $visited {
    &:visited {
      color: $visited;
    }
  }
  @if $focus {
    &:focus {
      color: $focus;
    }
  }
  @if $hover {
    &:hover {
      color: $hover;
    }
  }
  @if $active {
    &:active {
      color: $active;
    }
  }
}
```

I don't want to set anything to the first argument, which is $normal. I know I can set the values to their respective names like so:

```
@include link-colors($hover: $nav-link-hover-color, $active: $nav-link-hover-color);
```

However, this will give me an error, as I didn't assign anything to $normal.

As you can see, $normal is not optional; however, I only want to set colors to the others, not normal. It has already been set a color before, and I do not wish to override it.

Also, is there a way to set a value for all the arguments? Say `link-colors(white)` and it carries on to be set to all the arguments?

Comment: Then copy that mixin into your own mixin-file to overwrite and edit it…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to have **all** arguments be the same value, what you're looking for is a function that's commonly called *fill* or *array-fill* in other languages.  As long as you know exactly how many arguments the mixin takes, you're good to go:

```
@function array-fill($value, $n) {
    $list: ();
    @for $i from 1 through $n {
        $list: append($list, $value);
    }
    @return $list;
}

a {
  @include link-colors(array-fill(white, 5)...);
}
```

Output:

```
a {
  color: white;
}
a:visited {
  color: white;
}
a:focus {
  color: white;
}
a:hover {
  color: white;
}
a:active {
  color: white;
}
```

If you want to be able to specify specific values and *not* use the `$normal` argument, then you can do that by passing `null` as the value for that argument:

```
@include link-colors(null, $hover: $nav-link-hover-color, $active: $nav-link-hover-color);
```

Output:

```
a:hover {
  color: white;
}
a:active {
  color: white;
}
```

You can also combine these solutions:

```
a {
  @include link-colors(null, array-fill(white, 4)...);
}
```

Output:

```
a:visited {
  color: white;
}
a:focus {
  color: white;
}
a:hover {
  color: white;
}
a:active {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Exactly what I wanted. I had just found out about the ability to use `null` when you answered.